# .replace() is not working like it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, hide, show

I am trying to toggle a hidden input element when the select element has a certain option. When I am alerted of variable q, q has no input but variable put does I am quite confused as to why .replace() removes the entire string.

```
function hiddeninput(choice, put) {
    var q = put.replace(/./g, "").replace(/#/g, "");
    alert(put + "," + q);//alerts .other,
    if (choice === q) {
        $(put).show();
    } else {
        $(put).hide();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. JSfiddle has been quite buggy these past few days some of my previous working fiddles have stopped working, maybe that could be the reason.

Comment: Could you also post your HTML code?

Comment: Do you want to replace `"."` and `"#"`? Your `/./g` regex matches all characters, you should escape `\.` in your regex.

Comment: May I ask what is your expected output if `put = ".abc#123";`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that `.` is to match any character?

You need to escape it with a `\` so it will match just the `.` and not any character.

```
var q = put.replace(/\./g, "").replace(/#/g, "");
```

And instead of doing two replacements you can just do one

```
var q = put.replace(/[.#]/g,"");
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful especially the multiple character replacement. The code works now,

Answer (score 0):

In regex "." will match any character. You've got: `put.replace(/./g, "");`. This means you're replacing each match of any character with nothing, which will result in nothing.

If you want to match a dot, you need to escape the special character using a backslash: `put.replace(/\./g, "");`.

I'm not sure if this'll entirely solve your problem, but to me it seems like something unintended.

Comment: Thanks, my code works now. Coding is one of my hobbies, since I am no professional, there are bound to be many things I haven't learned, this happens to be one of those things.

Comment: My pleasure to help :) If either of these answers have helped to solve your question's problem then you should mark one of them as the answer ^_^ Otherwise if there's more information you need, edit the question and let us know how we can further help.